# Stopping the user from being taken away from our web site when viewing a YouTube video on our site

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I would like to stop user from being taken away from our web site when viewing a YouTube video embedded on our web site.

We are using YouTube iframe to display the video.

Here is the markup we are using:

```
<iframe 
   width="560" 
   height="315" 
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kffGRSuNlYA?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" 
      frameborder="0" 
      allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

Using the markup displayed above, the user can be directed to our YouTube channel. We want the user to stay on our web site when viewing videos we embedded using iframe.

We don't mind the YouTube logo being on the video.

Is there another attribute or parameter I can add to keep the user on our web site?

Comment: Please indicate the reason for the down vote and I will remove the portion of the posting that's incorrect because we really need to remove that logo. Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the posting to indicate that we want the user to stay on the web site and not be directed to our YouTube channel.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of going against their [terms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) of services so publicly. Google employees do pay attention to StackOverflow. They could find your site and ensure that youtube videos never play from it.

For youtube, you can pay to have the commercials removed. Perhaps, the same thing could be done with their branding (though I doubt that, web companies can be very protective about their branding).

Comment: Thanks. I will re-word my posting.